# Why does this pointer declaration work with malloc()?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am new to C and have a question about a specific pointer declaration:

Here is a program i wrote:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct n {

       int x;
       int y;
};


int main()
{
    struct n **p = malloc(sizeof(struct n));

    return 0;
}
```

The declaration here is not be correct but why not?

Here is my thought process:

- The man page of `malloc` specifies that it returns a pointer:

```
The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the
allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any built-in
type.
```

- The type of `p` is `struct n**` aka a pointer to another pointer.
- But shouldn't this declaration work in theory because:

1. `malloc` returns type `struct n*` (a pointer)
2. and `p` points to the pointer that `malloc` returns
3. so it is essentially a pointer to another pointer
4. so the type of `p` is fulfilled

Sorry if this is a dumb question but i am genuinely confused about why this does not work. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It will compile as written, but try to figure out how to add more code to use the double ptr. The wheels will come off the cart real quick...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of `malloc` is not `struct n *`, regardless of how it is called. The return type of `malloc` is `void *`.

Initializing a `struct n **` object with a value of type `void *` implicitly converts it to `struct n **`. This implicit conversion is allowed, because the rules for initialization follow the rules for assignment in C 2018 6.5.16.1 1, which state one of the allowed assignments is:

> … the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;…

> 2. and `p` points to the pointer that `malloc` returns

No, the value `p` is initialized to the value that `malloc` returns. Then `p` points to the memory `malloc` allocated.

It is a mistake for this code to allocate enough space for a `struct n` (using `malloc(sizeof(struct n))`) but assign the address of that space to the `struct n **` that is `p`. To point to a `struct n`, use `struct n *p = malloc(sizeof (struct n));` or, preferably, `struct n *p = malloc(sizeof *p);`.

To pointer to a pointer to a `struct n`, first create some pointer to a `struct n`, as with the above `struct n *p = malloc(sizeof *p);`. Then a pointer to that pointer would be `struct n **pp = &p;`.

If you wanted to allocate space for those pointers-to-pointers, you could do it with `struct n **pp = malloc(sizeof *pp);`, after which you could fill in the pointer to the `struct n` with `*pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);`. However, you should not add this additional layer of allocation without good reason.

Note that the form `MyPointer = malloc(sizeof *MyPointer);` is often preferred to `MyPointer = malloc(sizeof (SomeType));` because the former automatically uses the type that `MyPointer` points to. The latter is prone to errors, such as somebody misintepreting the type of `MyPointer` and not setting `SomeType` correctly or somebody later changing the declaration of `MyPointer` but omitting to make the corresponding change to `SomeType` in the `malloc` call.

Comment: This is a great answer thank you so much for taking the time to explain this, i greatly appreciate it. I have one last question: In your answer you mentioned using ```malloc(sizeof(*MyPointer))```, how does this exactly work? i can see that you dereference ```MyPointer``` but wouldnt that just lead to undefined behavior since it is in the middle of being assigned and potentially points to nothing? I am quite confused on how that would work.

Comment: @programme3219873: An expression operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated. The compiler only uses it to analyze its type.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really work. In this example, malloc is returning a void *, which points to a newly allocated place in the heap that is large enough to hold a struct n.

Note that malloc() returns type void *, which is basically a pointer to any potential type, malloc() DOES NOT return type struct n * (a pointer to your declared struct type). void * has the special property of being able to be cast to any other type of pointer, and back again.

All together this means that your code doesn't actually work, since the first dereference of your struct n** would be a struct n, not a struct n*. If you tried to dereference twice, you would most likely get an invalid memory reference and crash.

The reason that your code can compile and run without crashing is because:

1. The compiler automatically casts void * to struct n **
2. You never attempt to actually dereference your pointer, which means you never attempt an invalid memory reference.

Comment: "`void *` has the special property of being able to be cast to any other **object** type of pointer: " `void *` to/from a function pointer has issues.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I didn't realize that, I've honestly rarely used function pointers in C, but I suppose that makes sense since functions in C are not first class values. What kind of issues exactly?

Comment: Example: a function pointer might be 128-bit and `void *` 64-bit.  Saving such a function pointer into `void *` loses non-recoverable information if a conversion back to a function pointer is attempted.  C lacks a truly universal pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the problem and understanding may come:

```
int main()
{
    struct n data;
    struct n *pData = &data; // skipped in your version
    struct n **ppData = &pData;

    // struct n **ppData = &data; // Will not compile

    // struct n **ppData = (struct n **)&data; // Casting but wrong!

    return 0;
}
```

Because `malloc()` returns a void ptr, you are free to store the pointer into anything that is a pointer datatype. On your head if you put it into the wrong datatype...

Comment: Re “Because `malloc()` returns a void ptr, you are free to store the pointer into anything that is a pointer datatype”: `void (*f)() = malloc(1);` violates a constraint and will generate a diagnostic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You got me there. But, that function `returns` void (if that can be conceived.). It is not, itself, a void datatype. Apples and oranges, don't you think?

Comment: @Fe2O3: The result of `malloc` is not being stored into a function. That initialization asks to store it into a pointer.